# Multiple histogram plots from list using ggplot2-R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let say I have a list(list1) which elemnets are data frames(df1,df2,..,dfn) with same row numbers.

And let each data frame have different number of columns.

Let

```
list1[[1]]:

df1:


df$v1=rnorm(100);

df$v2=2*rnorm(100);

df$v3=3*rnorm(100);
```

How can I plot each variable's histogram using ggplot2 package?

@MLavoie I want 3 plots in 3 differrent graphs.

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you will need to be more specific. Do you want all three plot on one graph? or 3 different graphs? or 1 graph with 3 panels (using facet)? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424777/how-to-pass-a-list-to-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(v1=rnorm(100), v2=2*rnorm(100), v3=3*rnorm(100))
l = list(df,df,df)

lapply(
  l, 
  function(i) ggplot(df, aes(x=v1)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
)
```

Comment: I think you meant `function(i) ggplot(i, aes(x=v1)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)`?